# Preloader for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic page which takes about **8 seconds** to load searched data.

Problem is, all **browsers remain on old page** for those 8 secs & **show dynamic page** only after it

**loads completely.**

What I want is **preloder image**  to be shown to the customers until second page gets load.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are loading the second page through AJAX. If so, you'll only be able to display the results **after** the asynchronous call returns.

However, nothing prevents you from making changes to the page **before** sending off the AJAX request.  The basic structure will be:

```
var preload = $('<div></div>').text('I am preloading!').insertAfter('somewhere');
$.get(..., function() {
    preload.remove();
    // insert your real content, received from this AJAX request
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div id="busy">Loading...</div>')
        .ajaxStart(function() {$(this).show();})
        .ajaxStop(function() {$(this).hide();})
        .appendTo('body');
```

That's all!

You may want to add some style to `#busy` tag, but this you can do with CSS.